# "Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" x84-64 bit program running on aarch64 processor Debian 10

Tags: linux, eclipse, installation

Basically I'm trying to run eclipse's 64bit linux installer on a 64 bit linux machine, but it's giving me an exec format error. All other solutions I've seen say it's usually an error with it not being the right processor speed.

My question is twofold. 1) What is going on here? 2) How do I properly download and install Eclipse?

I'm running linux through chromebook

Here is the output of a few command line statements

```
uname@loc:~/Desktop/eclipse-installer$ ./eclipse-inst
-bash: ./eclipse-inst: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

uname@loc:~/Desktop/eclipse-installer$ file eclipse-inst
eclipse-inst: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b621fbc20e80d7ac375ece11a5775fc6686b71c7, with debug_info, not stripped

uname@loc:~/Desktop/eclipse-installer$ uname -m
aarch64
```

Comment: Wrong processor architecture (x86-64 code won't run on aarch64).  The current Eclipse 2020-06 doesn't have an aarch64 build. Eclipse 2020-09 due for release shortly has added an aarch64 build.

Comment: In addition what greg-499 says, there are not yet (2020-09) Eclipse IDE packages, but AArch64 (aka Arm64) Eclipse SDK 4.17 builds that [can be downloaded here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) (currently there is 4.17RC2). [Here you can follow the progress](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/showdependencytree.cgi?id=565419).

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your first question I think this could help:**
You are trying to execute a program designed to run on a "x86_64" based processor using a processor designed based on "aarch64" architecture. These are two distinct architectures although they both may be using 64-bits for addressing and so forth, but it's not the matter of the bits. They are two completely different CPU designs.

**For your second question** I can not help because I don't use Eclipse.